# Kivy: Changing first accordion item content to another by clicking a button inside the first content

Tags: python, accordion, kivy

I'm new to Kivy and I have an accordion with a dynamic number of items. Each item can have two different contents. You change the first content to the other by clicking a button inside the first content. Here's a simple example of this:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem

Builder.load_string('''
<MyAccordion>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

<MyAccordionItem>:
    FirstContent:

<FirstContent@GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    BoxLayout:
        ClickMeButton:
            text: 'Click me'
            on_press: self.change_content()

<SecondContent>:
    cols: 1
    GridLayout:
        rows: 1
        Label:
            text: 'You clicked!'
''')

class MyAccordionItem(AccordionItem):
    pass

class MyAccordion(Accordion):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyAccordion, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        for i in xrange(5):
            accordionitem = MyAccordionItem(title=str(i))
            self.add_widget(accordionitem)

class SecondContent(GridLayout):
    pass

class ClickMeButton(Button):
    def change_content(self):

        # how to reference the accordion item
        # this button belongs to?

        '''
        accordionitem = None
        accordionitem.clear_widgets()
        accordionitem.add_widget(SecondContent())
        '''

runTouchApp(MyAccordion())
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to reference the accordion item the button belongs to. I tried to chain parents and it gets to the the FirstContent object, but its parent seems to be a box layout for some reason (why?). Well, chaining parents is not the best idea anyways as it breaks easily if the content structure level changes.

I noticed that Kivy 1.8.1 will have a walk() method, but I guess that uses parents to traverse the tree upwards, so that might not work either?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code of change_button as below  . This is a way to refer what you want . There might be some other way to do this but hope this may help you :)

How we do it ?
1st parent is the box layout of the button in Class FirstContent ... BoxLayout you specified in the kv code above the  ClickMeButton

2nd parent i.e. above s parent is FirstContent

and so on ...

```
class ClickMeButton(Button):
    def change_content(self):
        print "I am clicked . I am button "
        print self.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.title

        #1kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x06ED9228 -- boxlayout in ClickMeButton
        #2<kivy.factory.FirstContent object at 0x06FCA1F0>   --Parent above
        #3<kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x06F591B8> -- Parent of firstcontent class as a boxlayout
        #4<kivy.uix.stencilview.StencilView object at 0x06F3B0A0>
        #5<kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x06FB7068>
        #6<__main__.MyAccordionItem object at 0x06ED8030>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that I had to go further to find the right ancestor. I created a recursive function to find MyAccordionItem so that I don't have to change the code if some other "parents" are added between the two in the chain

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with for the ClickMeButton class:

```
class ClickMeButton(Button):

    def change_content(self):

        accordionitem = self.find_anchestor(self.parent, 'MyAccordionItem')
        accordionitem.remove_widget(accordionitem.ids['_first_content'])
        accordionitem.add_widget(SecondContent())

    def find_anchestor(self, widget, classname):

        if widget:
            if widget.__class__.__name__ == classname:
                return widget

            else:
                return self.find_anchestor(widget.parent, classname)
```

In the kivy language string, I also needed to add `id: _first_content` below `FirstContent:` to give the instance an id that I can reference.

I created a recursive function `find_anchestor` to search for the correct parent. Paarth batra showed me that I can find the correct anchestor ultimately through parent chaining. But when the layout changes, I don't want to be adding or removing parents from the chain manually, so the recursive function goes up until it finds the correct one. Give it a widget to start from and the name of the widget class an instance of which you are looking for and it should work.

Once the correct parent widget is found, I need to remove the first content and add the second content. Since the first content is not a direct child of the accordionitem widget, I need to give it an id and reference that using the `ids` attribute.

Finally, I just add the second content.

I hope this helps someone with a similar issue in the future. And thanks paarth batra for your idea!

Answer (score 0):

Just give your AccordionItem/s an id and if for example you want all AccordionItems to be collapsed except the showing one (active_accordion_item), use that in your button:

on_release: active_accordion.collapse = False

- kivy will turn all other Acc/Items to True